# Limit ajax functionality to individual menu

Tags: javascript, ajaxify

I am trying to ajaxify the submenus on a couple of pages for a client. I'm currently testing on a localhost site I have set up.

These are the pages of the actual site that I'm working on. The food menus on [commonwealthskybar.com/menus/](http://www.commonwealthskybar.com/menus/) and the employees section down the page on [commonwealthskybar.com/about/](http://www.commonwealthskybar.com/about/)

I found this code that I tried to alter for the food menus I'd like to ajaxify by changing the contentSelector to #guts and the $menu section to '.menuLeft,.menuRight':

```
// History.js It!
// v1.0.1 - 30 September, 2012
// https://gist.github.com/854622
(function(window,undefined){

    // Prepare our Variables
    var
        History = window.History,
        $ = window.jQuery,
        document = window.document;

    // Check to see if History.js is enabled for our Browser
    if ( !History.enabled ) {
        return false;
    }

    // Wait for Document
    $(function(){
        // Prepare Variables
        var
            /* Application Specific Variables */
            contentSelector = '#guts',
            $content = $(contentSelector).filter(':first'),
            contentNode = $content.get(0),
            $menu = $('.menuRight,.menuLeft').filter(':first'),
            activeClass = 'active selected current youarehere',
            activeSelector = '.active,.selected,.current,.youarehere',
            menuChildrenSelector = '> li,> ul > li',
            completedEventName = 'statechangecomplete',
            /* Application Generic Variables */
            $window = $(window),
            $body = $(document.body),
            rootUrl = History.getRootUrl(),
            scrollOptions = {
                duration: 800,
                easing:'swing'
            };

        // Ensure Content
        if ( $content.length === 0 ) {
            $content = $body;
        }

        // Internal Helper
        $.expr[':'].internal = function(obj, index, meta, stack){
            // Prepare
            var
                $this = $(obj),
                url = $this.attr('href')||'',
                isInternalLink;

            // Check link
            isInternalLink = url.substring(0,rootUrl.length) === rootUrl || url.indexOf(':') === -1;

            // Ignore or Keep
            return isInternalLink;
        };

        // HTML Helper
        var documentHtml = function(html){
            // Prepare
            var result = String(html)
                .replace(/<\!DOCTYPE[^>]*>/i, '')
                .replace(/<(html|head|body|title|meta|script)([\s\>])/gi,'<div class="document-$1"$2')
                .replace(/<\/(html|head|body|title|meta|script)\>/gi,'</div>')
            ;

            // Return
            return result;
        };

        // Ajaxify Helper
        $.fn.ajaxify = function(){
            // Prepare
            var $this = $(this);

            // Ajaxify
            $this.find('a:internal:not(.no-ajaxy)').click(function(event){
                // Prepare
                var
                    $this = $(this),
                    url = $this.attr('href'),
                    title = $this.attr('title')||null;

                // Continue as normal for cmd clicks etc
                if ( event.which == 2 || event.metaKey ) { return true; }

                // Ajaxify this link
                History.pushState(null,title,url);
                event.preventDefault();
                return false;
            });

            // Chain
            return $this;
        };

        // Ajaxify our Internal Links
        $.menuS.ajaxify();

        // Hook into State Changes
        $window.bind('statechange',function(){
            // Prepare Variables
            var
                State = History.getState(),
                url = State.url,
                relativeUrl = url.replace(rootUrl,'');

            // Set Loading
            $.menuS.addClass('loading');

            // Start Fade Out
            // Animating to opacity to 0 still keeps the element's height intact
            // Which prevents that annoying pop bang issue when loading in new content
            $content.animate({opacity:0},800);

            // Ajax Request the Traditional Page
            $.ajax({
                url: url,
                success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR){
                    // Prepare
                    var
                        $data = $(documentHtml(data)),
                        $dataBody = $data.find('.document-body:first'),
                        $dataContent = $dataBody.find(contentSelector).filter(':first'),
                        $menuChildren, contentHtml, $scripts;

                    // Fetch the scripts
                    $scripts = $dataContent.find('.document-script');
                    if ( $scripts.length ) {
                        $scripts.detach();
                    }

                    // Fetch the content
                    contentHtml = $dataContent.html()||$data.html();
                    if ( !contentHtml ) {
                        document.location.href = url;
                        return false;
                    }

                    // Update the menu
                    $menuChildren = $menu.find(menuChildrenSelector);
                    $menuChildren.filter(activeSelector).removeClass(activeClass);
                    $menuChildren = $menuChildren.has('a[href^="'+relativeUrl+'"],a[href^="/'+relativeUrl+'"],a[href^="'+url+'"]');
                    if ( $menuChildren.length === 1 ) { $menuChildren.addClass(activeClass); }

                    // Update the content
                    $content.stop(true,true);
                    $content.html(contentHtml).ajaxify().css('opacity',100).show(); /* you could fade in here if you'd like */

                    // Update the title
                    document.title = $data.find('.document-title:first').text();
                    try {
                        document.getElementsByTagName('title')[0].innerHTML = document.title.replace('<','&lt;').replace('>','&gt;').replace(' & ',' &amp; ');
                    }
                    catch ( Exception ) { }

                    // Add the scripts
                    $scripts.each(function(){
                        var $script = $(this), scriptText = $script.text(), scriptNode = document.createElement('script');
                        scriptNode.appendChild(document.createTextNode(scriptText));
                        contentNode.appendChild(scriptNode);
                    });

                    // Complete the change
                    if ( $body.ScrollTo||false ) { $body.ScrollTo(scrollOptions); } /* http://balupton.com/projects/jquery-scrollto */
                    $body.removeClass('loading');
                    $window.trigger(completedEventName);

                    // Inform Google Analytics of the change
                    if ( typeof window._gaq !== 'undefined' ) {
                        window._gaq.push(['_trackPageview', relativeUrl]);
                    }

                    // Inform ReInvigorate of a state change
                    if ( typeof window.reinvigorate !== 'undefined' && typeof window.reinvigorate.ajax_track !== 'undefined' ) {
                        reinvigorate.ajax_track(url);
                        // ^ we use the full url here as that is what reinvigorate supports
                    }
                },
                error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
                    document.location.href = url;
                    return false;
                }
            }); // end ajax

        }); // end onStateChange

    }); // end onDomLoad

})(window); // end closure
```

When I tested it out, it worked great on the food menus. However, it was also affecting the main menu, and I was ending up with code appearing on pages.

What changes do I need to make so that only the submenus invoke the javascript?

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: I'm not seeing where it affects the main menu.

Comment: When I click a page on the main menu from one of the menu pages, the page gets loaded into the area where the food menu should be. When I start at the homepage and select a page, I get a block of code in the header and a block of code in the footer without the page reloading.

Comment: Could this be what's causing the other menu items to ajaxify?  '// Ajaxify our Internal Links
     $body.ajaxify();'

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out (don't ask me how). For anyone else looking for the answer, here's what I did.

I changed this:

```
// Ajaxify our Internal Links
$body.ajaxify();
```

to this:

```
// Ajaxify our Internal Links
$('.menuLeft,.menuRight').ajaxify();
```

I kept trying to add the menu classes here without the parentheses and single quotes. Once I got those in, everything fell into place. Now, only those menus are ajaxified.